# Making Universal game for iPhone and iPad (regular and Retina)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios-universal-app

I am making games on `Cocos2d` Engine and I have to make a Universal Game.
The practice I am following is described below. I have a set of 2 Images , one is Non HD and other is with -HD mentioned below.

Example:

> image1.png    -> I am using this just for Iphone

AND

> image1-hd.png   -> I am using this for Iphone-Retina, Ipad + 
>   Ipad-Retina

This is what I am following and thats a time taking task. Is there any other good and easy automatic procedure I can do or I have to stick with the procedure above?

Having 1 "Image.png" for Iphone saperately 
AND
Having 1 "Image-HD.png" for Iphone-Retina, Ipad +  Ipad-Retina (Which can give bad results on Ipad Retina and a bit on Ipad too)

Is this a good practice?

Comment: don't forget iPhone 5 layout ( use autolayout ). Here is a guide of naming: http://michaelgilkes.info/cocos2d-using-hd-images-for-ipad-in-a-universal-app/ ... `-hd` should be in lower case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's good practice, and the only practice I would recommend. In your case I would definitely consider adding -ipadhd resources as well, otherwise your game will look like a regular iPad game on the Retina iPad.

For the process I recommend [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). It has an Auto-SD feature that automatically rescales standard resolution images from the high resolution images. It automatically creates the corresponding atlas.png from atlas-hd.png and the ipad versions too.